# How can ADO.NET be forced to infer the type of Excel columns as String rather than Double?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, excel, ado.net

I have a column in an excel file that contains both strings and numbers. I found through trial and error that ADO.NET infers the type of the column depending on the type of the cells of the first 8 rows. When that happens, all the strings under the column simply don't get added to the DataTable.

My goal is to have ADO.NET read the values under that column as strings.

How can that be done?

Comment: What I found it that it only samples the first 8 rows.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281517

Comment: It all depends on the registry settings and IMEX. You need to check TypeGuessRows. 0 (zero) means all rows.

Comment: See @onedaywhen's answer http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/37/187667.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add imex = 1 to your connection string similar to:

```
    string sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
     "Data Source=" + savePath +
      "; Extended Properties=" + (char)34 + "Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;"
      + (char)34;
```

The IMEX parameter (1 is input mode) forces the data type of the column to text so that alphanumeric values are handled properly.